# Jquery to change background of <TD>

Tags: jquery, css

```
<td class="td_1">nbsp;</td><td class="td_1">nbsp;</td><td class="td_1">nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_2">nbsp;</td><td class="td_2">nbsp;</td><td class="td_2">nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_3">nbsp;</td><td class="td_3">nbsp;</td><td class="td_3">nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_4">nbsp;</td><td class="td_4">nbsp;</td><td class="td_4">nbsp;</td>
```

I need a jquery to change background of  to #00000 when mouseover and original colour when mouseout. These are dynamically generated in a loop so it can go up to td_100s.

I tried some examples but unfortunatelly the calss names are all static and didn't work for me.

If mouse over td_1 then all the td_1s should be affected accordingly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, you could just use CSS for that like `td[class^="td"]:hover{background-color:red;}`. Btw class names referring to HTML elements are probably a *confusing* idea

Comment: Why do you use class instead of id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need jQuery at all for the mouseover effect. CSS would do the job:

```
#table_id td {
  background: #ffffff;
 }

#table_id td:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

This presumes that your table has an ID or some other hook for the CSS.

UPDATING HEAVILY TO RESPOND TO THE OTHER CELL REQUIREMENT

Okay, if you want *all* the td's with the same class to change color, then yes, you will need some javascript.

Something like this should work:

```
$('td').hover(function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('td.' + thisClass).addClass('hovered');
}, 
   function(){
     var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
     $('td.' + thisClass).removeClass('hovered');
 }
```

Then in CSS:

```
.hovered { background: #000000; }
```

I generally try to just add/remove classes with jQuery, rather than do the color declarations in CSS - it's usually easier to maintain that way.

Comment: Why would this get -1? Not enough jQuery?

Comment: If mouse over td_1 then all the td_1s should be affected accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

i'd do the following: (i assume these `<td>`s are inside a `<table>` element) so you can add the class "table_class" to the table and define in a **css** two classes:

```
table.table_class td{
    background-color:#whatever;
}
table.table_class td:hover{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

**Note:** you don't need JQuery at all with this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why set the class names of the dynamic td rows??? Why not set their ids' to 'td_1' ... 'td_100'? and change their class when mouseover? Or how about css3 filters?

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay to do the hover for the whole row. Or modify this code to do `td` only

```
$("#mytable tr").mouseover(function() {$(this).addClass("over");}).mouseout(function() {$(this).removeClass("over");});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, make a class for

```
td.hoverstate{background-color:#000;}
```

Then in jQuery do

```
   $("td").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass("hoverstate");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hoverstate");
      }
    );
```

Comment: That is a good point, he asked for jQuery so I thought I'd supply that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/hKmTU/3/.  I've got it working the way you've asked for. chipcullen's answer won't work because you need to parse out the hover class.

For example:
When you hover over all td_1s, the class becomes "td_1 hovered".

Then when you try to use thisClass in the selector you end up with "td.td_1 hovered", which will not select the proper divs

```
var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
$('td.' + thisClass).removeClass('hovered');

becomes

var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
thisClass = thisClass.substring(0, thisClass.indexOf(" "));
$("td." + thisClass ).removeClass('hovered');
```

Hope this helps!